# VS2022 CE: create console app targetting .net standard 4.6.1

Tags: .net, frameworks, console-application

I am trying to create a console app targetting this specific framework.
I installed the framework, but in VS2022CE I only get the options for .NET 6.0 or 7.0

I NEED this specific framework to use a specific library.
Anybody have any idea how I might be able to create the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a Console App from the .NET Core template. You should instead choose the 'Console App (.NET Framework)' template, where you should be able to see it.